# handle Null and Default values in @RequestBody with Jackson

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have timezone POJO as below:

```
@Entity
public class TimeZoneDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "timezone_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "timezone_sequence", sequenceName = "t_timeZone_master_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String timeZone;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private double hourDifference;
    /* all gettet/setter */
}
```

I have updateTimeZone method in Spring Controller as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateTimezone", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateTimezone(@RequestBody TimeZoneDto timeZoneDto){

}
```

when I pass request as below:

```
{"id":14,"name":"America/Los_Angeles -7:00 GMT"}
```

then it automatically convert other values with default values when map with POJO and it becomes:

```
id=14, timeZone=null, name=America/Los_Angeles -7:00 GMT, hourDifference=0.0
```

because of this when I update this POJO as below

```
getEntityManager().merge(timezoneDto);
```

it override TimeZone = null and hourDifference = 0.0 automatically,

so is there any way by which my TimeZoneDto in @RequestBody has only those columns which I pass in request JSON.

**EDIT**

I have used below on Class but its not work

```
  @JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_EMPTY)
                 OR  
  @JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: What you want these values default to? I mean when Jackson deserializes the JSON, by default it just creates the DTO as a plain java object and all absent fields will take their default values.

Comment: I want to ignore all absent fields from DTO object when Jackson deserialize the JSON

Comment: I don't understand, Jackson already ignored those fields that's why they got default values. What do you need those non-existent fields in the JSOn to be in the DTO?

Comment: I don't want Default values in my DTO for those properties which are not in JSON. because in such case it overrides my existing persistent values with Default values.

Comment: You can't do that with your current set up.

Comment: is there any other way by which I can achieve this ?

Comment: Have a look at the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your design. You mix your Entities with DTOs. A mostly used solution is to separate these two layers. You can have a common interface say `TimeZoneInfo` then have two implementations

- `TimeZoneDto` - responsible for transferring data between client and server, you only declare what you need in this object. (ex: without timeZone field)
- `TimeZoneEntity` - represent a persistent entity (JPA/Hibernate)

Then you can have `TimeZoneDto` as the request body and adapt (i.e get required values and set to entity) that object as `TimeZoneEntity`. You may need to fetch the `TimeZoneEntity` from DB before adapting this DTO. I would say preferably in a service/delegate class not in rest controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic pattern where you first need to fetch the `TimeZone` entity from your storage repository and then merge the incoming JSON data with the existing record data.

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateTimeZone(@RequestBody TimeZoneDto dto) {
  final TimeZone timeZone = timeZoneRepository.findById( dto.getId() );
  // use object mapper or whatever and merge dto onto timeZone
  timeZoneRepository.saveOrUpdate( timeZone );
  return timeZone;
}
```

Comment: so is there any way by which my TimeZoneDto in @RequestBody has only those columns which I pass in request JSON.?

Comment: Your DTO will be populated by Jackson with the fields your JSON contains.  The other fields will simply be null; that is the way Jackson hydrates a JSON stream to an Object.  From this point forward, you have to address the logical merge of attributes as I described above.

Comment: if all those fields are NULL which are not in JSON than I can merge using some conditions, but in my case some Long , boolean variable takes default , so sometimes that may be actual values and sometimes they are default. so its hard for me to distinguish